# How to use initialize a service in a controller during unit testing in grails?

Tags: grails, spock

I'm starting with unit testing in **Grails 3.3.8**, I have the **ControllerSpec**:

```
class FooControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<FooController> {

      void "test index"() {
        given:
        controller.fooService = new FooServiceImplementation()

        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.json
        status == 200
      }

      void "test show"() {
        given:
        controller.fooService = new FooServiceImplementation()

        when:
        params['id'] = '000001400'
        controller.show()

        then:
        status == 200
      }
    }
```

**FooService** is an interface, does not have implementation.

```
@Service(Foo)
interface FooService {
Foo get(Serializable id)

List<Foo> list(Map args)
}
```

I create a **FooServiceImplementation** like this:

```
class FooServiceImplementation implements FooService {
 Foo get(Serializable id) {/*implementation here*/}

    List<Foo> list(Map args) {/*implementation here*/}
}
```

This actually works, but there is another form to initialize the service in my controller?
I want to use the FooService exactly with the implementation that grails would compile when injecting the service into the controller, this to make sure that the results during the execution will be the same as during the testing, since my FooServiceImplementation could generate different results, although I suppose you should write the implementation correctly.

Comment: "I want to use the FooService exactly with the implementation that grails would compile when injecting the service into the controller..." - If you want to use the real implementation, why does `FooServiceImplementation` exist?

Comment: Because the service is null when test, and cannot use controller.fooService = new FooService ().

Comment: If you want to a reference to an instance of the real service, you can get that data store.  See section https://guides.grails.org/grails-gorm-data-services/guide/index.html for an example.  You can assign that to the corresponding property in the controller in your test if you like, or interact with it directly.